# Lightsail Laravel Bitnami setup - Default page loads instead of application

Tags: laravel, apache, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Set up Laravel on a Lightsail following the official guide here:https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/get-started/use-laravel/

But my server IP still returns the default You are now running LAMP page instead of my application.

Restarted apache as instructed after editing the hosts file to no avail

Here is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
        ServerAlias *
        DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public
        <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public">
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

and my https-host file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Restarted apache like so:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please offer up some more details. What have you tried? What does your config look like? Refer here for tips on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mike Thank you. I have now added some more info.

Comment: Looks like your web root is set to /opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public. Is that where you're copying your files to?

Comment: @Mike /opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME is my Laravel folder root
/public is a folder inside APPNAME that contains the frontend resources

Comment: The public folder is the actual stuff that will be served to the browser. The other inner workings of the framework should be private. So sounds like that's configured correctly. Can you try replacing 127.0.0.1:80 and 127.0.0.1:443 with *:80 and *:443? You also probably need enable the apache2 rewrite module for Laravel to work. If it's installed, you can just type "a2enmod rewrite" in your terminal and then restart apache. Then in your <Directory> section, add another line that says RewriteEngine On